When creating a NEW primary tracker domain in Pardot, will all Assets get the new Tracker Domain? Or is that a manual update?
We are creating a new domain site wide and sunsetting the old one with redirects. That being said we will need to create a new Tracker Domain in Pardot. As the Admin I am having a hard time understanding if I need comb thru all the assets that are always on or "live" and update them one by one with the new Primary Tracker Domain? Or after creating it and setting it as the primary does the system do it for me?
Having a hard time finding the answer to that.
